# webview element is not loading in reactjs application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I have created a function that returns `WebView`

```
const WebviewComponent = () => (
  <webview id="test" src="https://www.google.com" style={{ height: "700px", width:"800px", autoSize:"on", minWidth:"576", minHeight:"432" }} />
)
```

and I called this function in app.js. When I try to launch the application the src url is not loading.

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` source type is not a `string`. You should check `WebView` [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview#usage) or see the usage below to understand how it works.

**Usage**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

class MyWebComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/' }} />;
  }
}
```

In your case, It will be

```
const WebviewComponent = () => (
  <WebView
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com' }} />
)
```